# Why limit execution cores if you're not an cloud provider

Tags: virtual-machines, multi-core

We're maintaining development of a system installed at a customer site on their virtual server. This application will at times need to run heavy work. However it's only been granted a single core.

I see the need to avoid an application running amok and bringing all other applications to a halt. This should be easily avoidable by not giving any application access to more than half the processors.

It seems like some customers manage their virtual machines as if they're cloud providers; giving each application as little as possible. This makes sense for a cloud provider who can then charge extra for upgrades, but for a customer this will in my view only result in underutilization.

Is there an established good practice for core administration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an established good practice for core administration?

You already gave the answer: give each application as little as possible.

Ideally the vendor system requirements documentation gives reasonable sizing recommendations  (and not as often seen an overly large amount of CPU cores/memory/IOPS just to be safe and always prevent potential performance issues). I like to see a minimum supported configuration and a sizing table:

- usage scenario A  -> Hardware requirements B
- usage scenario X  -> Hardware requirements Y

Comment: To add some more explanation: assigning too many CPU cores may lead to real problems and wasted resources. For example a VM with 4 cores can only be scheduled to execute when all cores are available, even if it only needs a single core. -- At least on VMware I have seen servers with 50% wait time that disappeared after downscaling its VMs.

Comment: @mschuett Is VMware really that rigid? Are other VM's the same? This is an argument I can understand, but in my view it really undermines the usefulness of VM's at least for non-cloud providers.

Comment: In general every VM hypervisor has the same problem, VMware is not particularly bad, just the one I have the most experience with it. As far as I know there are similar effects on KVM; you also hear it from EC2 instances, but there you never know if they are caused by the (Xen) hypervisor or by noisy 'neighbour VMs'.

Answer (score 0):

The application will of course need to benefit from multiple cores before giving it more than one helps.  Some are single threaded.

Regarding recovery from spinning processes, typical counterargument will be to write better software that doesn't do that, and that the OS will still be responsive enough to recover.

For the very best response time during high utilization, latency sensitive environments may decide to not oversubscribe processor cores. This gets expensive to round up, even with 12 or 18 core sockets.